# How can I block my ISP's search engine?

Tags: dns, isp

I have Verizon internet but I've seen this with other ISPs as well. If I click something that looks like a link but isn't, I get redirected to a Verizon search page saying "no results for link.fakedomain" filled with ads. I'd like to just get a regular HTTP error page instead. Is there some DNS setting I need to use for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using DNS servers other than the ones your ISP provides.

This would need to be manually set in your operating system's network settings.  For Windows: Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> right click on network adapter, then Properties, then double-click on "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)".

You can try 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google), or 1.1.1.1 amd 1.0.0.1 (Cloudflare), and there are many others.

On Windows you'll need to uncheck the box that says "Obtain DNS server address automatically", then manually enter the addresses.

You'll need to do this on your wireless adapter and any wired Ethernet adapter that's there as well.

If that doesn't work: It's possible your ISP intercepts outgoing traffic on UDP port 53 and will force you to use their DNS.  You then need to use DNS-over-HTTPS (DoH).  Firefox supports this and it can be configured in its settings.